# Conversion tracking script - no HTTP response detected

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to insert a conversion tracking script into a thank you page that one is directed to upon completing a contact form. I'm working in Wordpress and using the WPWOX Custom Script Integration plugin to insert my script, which is as follows:

```js
<!-- Google Code for contact-us/thank-you Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 978060811;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "OmTcCKWT6mQQi4yw0gM";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/978060811/?label=OmTcCKWT6mQQi4yw0gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

However, when running Tag Assist I am given the error of "No HTTP response detected".

Any idea why I I'm getting the error? Here is the link to the thank you page http://expoprop.co.za/thank-you/

Comment: Recommended Action: Reinstall the Google Analytics snippet by removing the current iteration, copy a new version from the Analytics interface, and insert that version into the site.

Comment: @silver-brush I am having same issue.please tell how you solved this issue

Comment: There was a flaw in my code, I regenerated it and it worked.